# send email to Outlook group EXCLUDING one person

Tags: ms-access, powershell, outlook, vba

I have an Access DB through which we email reports to a list of outlook email addresses. This list contains email groups.

I want to be able to programatically send an email to a group, but NOT send the email to a specific member of the group.

Unfortunately, this person cannot be removed from the group, because he still needs to be able to receive emails sent to him via the group email, from other departments.

Also, I cannot simply split the group apart into its constituents because I cannot keep adding emails to the script each time a new member is added to the Outlook group.

Can anyone advise a way to snipe the email being sent to this one specific address within an Outlook group?

I prefer a VBA solution, but might also be able to implement with PowerShell.

**Edit** - here is my code so far.

Here is the function that sends the email:

```
Function SendEmails(SystemID As String, _
                    DistributionGROUPID As String, _
                    subjectID As String, _
                    EmailIDBody As String, _
                    Optional Attachments As Variant)

    Dim Subject As String
    Dim SendTo As Variant
    Dim CopyTo As Variant
    Dim BlindCopyTo As Variant
    Dim ReplyTo As Variant
    Dim emailBody As String
    Dim Attachement As Variant

    Subject = GetEmailSubject(SystemID, subjectID)
    SendTo = GetEmailAddresses(SystemID, DistributionGROUPID, 1)
    CopyTo = GetEmailAddresses(SystemID, DistributionGROUPID, 2)
    BlindCopyTo = GetEmailAddresses(SystemID, DistributionGROUPID, 3)
    ReplyTo = GetEmailAddresses(SystemID, DistributionGROUPID, 4)
    emailBody = GetEmailBody(SystemID, EmailIDBody)

    If IsArray(Attachments) Then
        Attachement = Attachments
    End If

    ' Call Send Email
    SendMails _
        Subject, _
        Attachement, _
        SendTo, _
        CopyTo, _
        BlindCopyTo, _
        ReplyTo, _
        emailBody

End Function
```

And here is the function that grabs email addresses from an Access table and loads them into a string. I added a comment showing where I might insert some code / reference to a function that will open each email address and determine whether it is a group. **To those of you who know what they are doing** - is this the right approach, or is this even possible? I will do a bit of googling and attempt to stumble through, but if someone can provide a solution, it will be much appreciated.

```
Function GetEmailAddresses(SystemID As String, Business As String, RecipientType As Integer) As Variant

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim lSubject As String
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qry_Email_Get_Email_Addresses")

    qdf.Parameters(0) = SystemID
    qdf.Parameters(1) = Business
    qdf.Parameters(2) = CDbl(RecipientType)

    Dim RS As Recordset
    Set RS = qdf.OpenRecordset

    If RS.RecordCount = 0 Then

        ReDim arr(1)
        arr(0) = ""

    Else

        RS.MoveLast
        ReDim arr(RS.RecordCount - 1)
        RS.MoveFirst
        Dim offset As Integer
        offset = 0
        Do While Not RS.EOF
        ' change here? open up outlook object, determine if email is a group.
        ' if group, then create inner loop that adds individual emails to 'arr' array, excluding specific address.
            arr(offset) = RS![Email_Address]
            offset = offset + 1
            RS.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing

    GetEmailAddresses = arr

End Function
```

Comment: Are you using the outlook object model?  Can you show some code that you've tried so far?

Comment: yes, please give me a minute.

Comment: @roryap - please see my edit. i was mistaken - the outlook object model is not being used. we are instead using CDO model. Let me know if you want to see the method that implements the CDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the AddressEntry.Members collection and add only the members that you want one at a time instead of sending to the whole DL.

Comment: I read up on [this collection on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.members.aspx) and it is deprecated. Will it work in Access 2010?